# Is it possible to scan the top X UDP ports and the top Y (X!=Y) TCP ports in Nmap using a single command?

Tags: nmap, tcp, udp, scan

Given X!=Y, is there any way to scan the top (--top-ports) X TCP ports and the top Y UDP ports using a simple Nmap command?

The --top-ports parameter affects both the TCP and UDP scans (e.g., when -sSU is used).

If exists, short/simple command is preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this post](http://seclists.org/nmap-dev/2011/q2/365) it looks like the best way to do this would be to find out what the port lists for each option are and then supply them as a list of ports to scan on the command line, as you can specify different lists of TCP and UDP ports to scan using the `-p` option by using `T:` and `U:`

To quote the relevant part of that post

> but I first generate the list of top UDP ports (10 in this case):
>
> ./nmap -oX - -sU --top-ports 10
>
> The output 'scaninfo' line includes the services list in Nmap format:
>
> 53,67,123,135,137-138,161,445,631,1434
>
> So then I can run Nmap with:
>
> -p T:1-65535,U:53,67,123,135,137-138,161,445,631,1434 `